# Git change history of feature-branch into a new branch?

Tags: git, version-control, github, branch, dvcs

Someone else can better reword this question, but here is what I want to do:

I have been working on a long lived major-refactor branch B. I have been regularly merging master in and by now branch B is ahead of master by ~200 commits. I am ready to send a pull request now but I want to cleanup my commit history a bit. Basically I want to squash all my ~200 commits into just 3 commits:

- Commit 1 = All files that got deleted
- Commit 2 = All new added files
- Commit 3 = Everything else i.e. all moved/editted files

And, just so I don't screw it up, I would like to do this history-rewrite on a separate branch from my own branch B and send in that branch as my pull request.

What's the easiest way I can achieve this in git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you are going to merge to `master`:

1. Create and checkout a new branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b going-to-squash
   ```
2. Rebase onto master

   ```
   git rebase --squash master
   ```
3. Reset to the master branch

   ```
   git reset master
   ```
4. Now, your entire squashed branch will be in an un-committed state.

   Create your new commits now.

   I would use a gui for this step, but it's perfectly doable on the command line.

Comment: see those answers for step 4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972071/946789 (VSCode commit selected ranges) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085191/946789 (`git add -patch`, staging only "hunks")

Answer (score 1):

A `git rebase --interactive` (as [described in the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages)) wouldn't be practical, as it allows to pick or squash commits (not parts of commits)

Another way might be to [generate a giant patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432396/create-a-patch-by-comparing-a-specific-branch-on-the-remote-with-a-specific-loca) (like `git format-patch origin/master`) and then parse that file make 3 patch files:

- one with all the deletetions
- one with all the additions
- the rest

You can then create a branch from the the commit `branch B` originated (see "[Reference Git branch start commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458055/reference-git-branch-start-commit)"), and apply those three patches.