# How can I commit some changes to a file, but not others, in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has excellent git integration but I can't find a way to do partial commits. Basically, I want to be able to select specific changes in my files and stage them without staging the entire file. This functionality is supported by the git CLI, Github native apps, and Atom plugins.

Mostly making sure I'm not just missing something before opening a ticket for it.

Comment: I wish 1) their next hunk shortcut (Alt + F5) would go across files related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24389 | https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50434 and 2) that there was a way to add hunks without the need to select lines when you want the entire hunk https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48323 | https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13740

Answer (score 671, accepted):

- Open up the Source Control view, then click a changed file to open the comparison.
- Select the lines you want to stage.
- Click '...' then `Stage Selected Ranges` *(in the ··· at the top-right corner of the editor, **not** the ··· at the top of the git panel on the left)*.

[image]

Comment: Just in case someone else gets confused like I did: this screenshot refers to the `···` at the top-right corner of the editor, not the `···` at the top of the git panel on the left.

Comment: If this returns you an error "*Git: Illegal value for `line`*", this has been reported a couple of times on GitHub, but still not fixed. In that case, just toggle "Inline view" and it'll work. [Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35705#issuecomment-343638025)

Comment: As mentioned by @Dimitris, this command is also in the Command Palette, so you don't need to be in Source Control view.

Comment: Be aware, this stages whole lines, if you want to stage portions of a line, I guess it's back to `get add -i` and interactive editing...

Comment: This doesn't work, nothing happens when clicking on 'Stage selected ranges'.

Comment: is there any method to lock the file so that it never STAGE

Comment: @Lee If you select lines in the old content (the left side of the editor), nothing happens.

Comment: For DELETED lines, you need to select the lines above and below the deleted line(s) for this to work since you can't select deleted lines ...since they are deleted, LOL :-D

Comment: Is this feature disabled in .ipynb files? Your solution worked fine for all other file types except my jupyter notebooks. Is there a workaround to get this functionality for .ipynb as well?

Answer (score 308):

> ⚡ Summing up everything in this post with a gif.

1. Make sure you're in the source control view to use this feature
2. Select the range of code
3. Open `···` at the top-right corner of the editor (not the `···` at the top of the git panel on the left)
4. You can also press <kbd>COMMAND (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>COMMAND (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open keyboard shortcuts and search for `range` and then set a keyboard shortcut for this action.

[image: VSCode Range Select Commit]

Peace! ✌️

Comment: hard to select deleted lines

Comment: @duXing To select *deleted* lines, try to highlight the empty shaded gap representing those deleted lines, and be sure to include the line before and after the gap in your selection. This should allow **Stage Selected Ranges** to stage the deleted content.

Comment: how to select and mark multiple parts of a code snippet?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari: You can add them one after the others.

Comment: mine does not have that range option

Answer (score 94):

**Update: October 2017:** In the latest VSCode as of October 2017 (version 1.18) you can actually stage specific lines really easy just like you would do it with the git CLI `git add -p`. You just have to click on the edited line from the side like,  watch the diff and apply it or not.

[image: View pending changes and perform partial commits in the editor]

Comment: There are two things missing though... You can't split hunks and you can't manually edit hunks... :(

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: It's possible like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972071/6419007 And it's actually very convenient. If you just need some part of a hunks, you can select the corresponding lines.

Comment: @EricDuminil Not sure how long have you been using VSCode, but at the time of writing of my comment (and the original question), that wasn't at all possible. Sure VSCode has become more mature and partial staging is actually working really nice these days. I've just used it recently (last week).

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: VSCode definitely got better with time. If your comment isn't up-to-date anymore, you could delete it.

Comment: @EricDuminil Why? Are you going through all of your SO activity at least on a yearly basis and delete outdated questions, answers and comments? Every comment has a datetime stamp on it. I understand you didn't check it. 

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: That's the purpose of the community. If somebody notices and tells me that my answer or comment is now wrong or outdated, yes, I'm happy to delete the content. Your highly upvoted comment could lead people to believe it's not worth it to look for a solution. Anyway, as you wish, regardless how old your comment is.

Answer (score 35):

initially, I've made an overview of available methods, but I think this bit should be on top since it's the most useful one:

## What I've came up with to make it quicker

As one can see, "Git: Stage Selected Ranges" shown by Command Palette (`ctrl + shift + P`) for the main editor has the same hotkey as in the "review changes" interface, but it doesn't actually work. For some time, I thought this is a bug, but it turned out to be a configurable behavior: click the settings button:

[image]

(or just go `ctrl + K ctrl + S`/file → preferences → keyboard shortcuts and search for `@command:git.stageSelectedRanges`)

...and you'll see that by default the "When" expression is `isInDiffEditor`, so it is not supposed to work in the normal editor. So, **change When expression to empty**:

[image]

And either keep the default hotkey combination and use it in the editor (that's what I did) or set it to something shorter (not a double-combination, I'll consider this too). Profit!

If something's unclear or you want to know other options, here's

## The initial overview of available methods

- basic method is to Stage Selected Ranges in the interface for **reviewing changes**:

  [image]

  1. open Source Control (`ctrl + shift + G`)
  2. select file
  3. select lines that should be staged (or put a cursor for a single line or lines before and after deleted bits)
  4. open the "..." menu and select "Stage Selected Ranges"
- on the other hand, you can use **hotkeys**. Default ones (in v1.56.2) are `ctrl + K` and then `ctrl + alt + S`. To set custom key combination, open Keyboard shortcuts (either from File → Preferences or via `ctrl + K` then `ctrl + S`) and find `stageSelectedRanges` (and may be `unstageSelectedRanges`, `revertSelectedRanges`)
- unfortunately, hotkeys mentioned above work only in the "review changes" interface, and you may want to do this **in the code editor directly**. You can do this via another interface: click the change label:

  [image]

  and then the "stage change" button:

  [image]
- despite there's no direct **hotkeys** to stage selected range **from code editor**, you can go `ctrl + shift + P` (open Command Palette) and then type "stage s" and choose "Git: Stage Selected Ranges":

  [image]

Also, it's handy to use `Alt + F5` to jump to the next change in the file when you review what to stage.

Comment: This is one click in Intellij, maybe worth the cost for an IDE, in terms of workflow.

Comment: @godhar may be there are plugins that make this one-click, but I prefer hotkeys anyway, so haven't researched this aspect that much

Answer (score 25):

This option has been added to the command palette:

###### on Mac:

`shift`+`command`+`P` and type "Stage Selected Ranges"

###### on Windows:

`control`+shift`+`P` and type "Stage Selected Ranges"

Next time you open the command palette you don't have to type in, just press enter (the tool preselect your last command).

###### Manually

*Help* > *Show All Commands* > and type "Stage Selected Ranges"

Answer (score 2):

Use Interactive staging.

command - git add -p <file_name>
this will show you the file, and you can choose which one you want to commit after parting the changes

Comment: The question is about VS Code. It seems the asker is already aware of this since the question has this clause: "This functionality is supported by the git CLI..."