# Is it possible to choose what modifications will be pushed in GIT for app.config

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

Each developpers have a different connection string to use their own database in app.config file. But this file must be versionned in GIT because we add some app settings.

Is there a way to do that in Visual Studio ? We can do in GitHub desktop to choose if some pieces of code not to be pushed but if we could do the same in VS, it will be greater.

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: is that what you want to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085162/commit-only-part-of-a-file-in-git ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partially stage files with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225582/partially-stage-files-with-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment provided by Shayki Abramczyk could help you.

As Matthieu Charbonnier mentioned in the case: he could use SourceTree to just index the partial chunk he need, and do rest of the selection and the commit in Visual Studio (VS understand and split the file in two modifications).

You can also try the method that morty mentioned in the case:Using GitTools integrated into vs.In advanced mode (checkbox above the file list) you can stage or reset selected lines. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yysun.GitTools

For other methods and details,please refer to the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225582/partially-stage-files-with-visual-studio).