# Visual Studio Code - merge one line at time

Tags: git, merge, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code 1.20.0 and I have a merge conflict in my file.
I want to keep both my edits and the remote ones, so I'd like to add one line at time to my commit. Following some screenshots and (I hope) a better explanation (on the left there is the local file, on the right the remote versione of the file).
[image]
What if I want to add the highlighted line to my local file? Clicking on the 'plus' icon won't do anything.
[image]
And what if now I want to keep my local change to the file? Here the 'plus' and 'minus' icons won't do anything too.
[image]
Until now I could only use this 'plus' button that automatically accepts all the remote changes to one file, but this will overwrite my local edits. 
Is there a way to achieve what I need? Do I need to install some plugin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I commit some changes to a file, but not others, in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730585/how-can-i-commit-some-changes-to-a-file-but-not-others-in-vscode)