# Review changes before commit in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In IntelliJ I usually use CTRL+K to bring up a sort of change review screen before committing. I can step through each change one by one using F7.

Does any body know the equivalent extension in VSCode?

I have tried gitLens and git diff history. Both do not seem to provide that functionality.

Comment: This is the number one feature that keeps me coming back to IntelliJ. I feel blind without it. And it explains why so many other developers accidentally leave debug code in their PRs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the functionality is not identical, but you can go to the Source Control tab (ctrl + shift + G on Windows) and see the changes in the files, stage or unstage some files and commit. The downside compared to the Idea's feature is the files are shown fully, without skipping lines which were not changed. And also one can't pick the changes in a file to be committed, only commit them all (but still choose files to commit) – this drawback isn't related to the asked question though.

PS actually, I was wrong about the second drawback, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68257756/3995261).